# JavaScript String letters and numbers check

Tags: javascript

I have a variable that has a value of 6 characters and I need to check if the characters have 3 letters and 3 numbers in that order. The only problem is how to do that.

Comment: Please explain the problem with sample inputs and expected outputs.

Comment: Do you mean the value of the variable? You could use "regular expression". Google that.

Comment: Please ask one question at a time, and don't change your question in midstream. Don't mark some part of your question as UPDATE. No one cares when you changed what, and if they do, they can look at the history. If you do update your question, don't forget to update the title too if necessary.

Comment: My apologies @torazaburo. This is my first time here in stackoverflow to ask a question. And I appreciate the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function isValid(str){
    return /[a-z]{3}[0-9]{3}/i.test(str)    
}
```

Comment: @xZVanG can this result to a boolean? thanks for the answer btw

Comment: Yes, returns a boolean - Try: isValid("abc123")

Comment: just tested this. thanks

Answer (score 1):

For variable value:

```js
function isValid(str){
    return /[a-z]{3}[0-9]{3}/i.test(str)    
}

var items = ["abc123", "geese", "foobar", "aso812"]

for(var i = 0;i < items.length;i++){
  item = items[i];
  alert(isValid(item));
  }
```

For variable name:

```js
var obj = {
    abc123: "foo",
    a123bc: "bar"
}
for (var item in obj){
  alert(isValid(item.toString()));
  }

function isValid(str){
    return /[a-z]{3}[0-9]{3}/i.test(str)    
}
```

Comment: It's not clear the OP is worrying about the variable **name**, although his question is worded poorly; it's more likely he's worried about its **value**.

Comment: Ah, @torazaburo, the code can be easily modified to accept that :)

Answer (score 0):

Use a [regular expression](http://regular-expressions.info).

```
function hasThreeLetters(str) {
    return !!(''+str).match(/^[a-z]{3}$/i);
}

var x = 'abc';
hasThreeLetters(x); // returns true
```

Note: The `!!` converts the result of calling `.match()`, which will be an array if the string matches the regular expression or null if it doesn't, into a boolean. The `(''+str)` converts `str` into a string if it wasn't already one, so you can then call `.match()` on it.